# ActiveMQ Artemis: Change log level online

Tags: logging, configuration, activemq-artemis

Is there any way to change the ActiveMQ Artemis logging configuration online? Sometimes it is helpful to increase the level to TRACE or DEBUG without restarting the broker instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `java.util.logging:type=Logging` MBean to inspect and change the level of individual loggers. The ActiveMQ Artemis web console exposes this via the "JMX" tab, e.g.:

[image: logging config]

Keep in mind:

- This won't change the `level` of the relevant handlers in your `etc/logging.properties` so if you set a logging to `TRACE` but the `level` for the `handler` is only `DEBUG` then you'll only get `DEBUG` logging.
- These changes are *volatile*. As soon as the broker is restarted the changes will be lost.

Lastly, it's worth noting that by default changes in `etc/logging.properties` are picked up dynamically by the broker at runtime so if you have access to that file it might be a better option to change it directly.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, Artemis picks up changes in `logging.properties`. Cool! Should be mentioned in the docs …